# Sending links to Page Viewer from list (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint, filter, sharepoint-2013

I use the Page Viewer to integrate html files to our SharePoint. However, I have multiple links from the same category for which I would like to use within the same SharePoint page containing the Page Viewer. Which filter app would be best suited for this and how can I connect it to the Page Viewer?

(Using SharePoint Server 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Page Viewer render as iframe so you could update the src to point to other page.

Sample demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdatePageViewerLink() {
        $('iframe[name*="MSOPageViewer"]').attr("src", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_tasking_order");
    }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="UpdatePageViewerLink()" type="button" value="button" />
```